# Alpha Vantage Currency in Global Quote

Tags: alpha-vantage

When you make a Quote Endpoint call from the Alpha Vantage API, for example (https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo), you don't get currency with it.

How can I know which currency is being used for the price listed in the response?

Sample response:

```
{
    "Global Quote": {
        "01. symbol": "MSFT",
        "02. open": "162.8235",
        "03. high": "163.2200",
        "04. low": "161.8250",
        "05. price": "162.2000",
        "06. volume": "10067390",
        "07. latest trading day": "2020-01-10",
        "08. previous close": "162.0900",
        "09. change": "0.1100",
        "10. change percent": "0.0679%"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whichever exchange the company is listed on lists the price in their currency of choice. That is the currency that is returned.

---

For example in the API call [above](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo), the currency will be in USD since MSFT is listed on the NASDAQ (An exchange in the United States)

However, a call like for ticker BP.LON will result in the currency being in GBX since the ticker is listed on the London exchange.

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=BP.LON&apikey=XXX

Comment: Is there an API which will return this info?

Comment: You can look into intrinio, quandl, xignite, polygon, or IEXCloud. I'm not sure if they have exactly that but they might.

Comment: I guess I meant does the AlphaVantage API have an endpoint which will return the name of the currency used for reporting the value of a security. I guess the answer is no… Thanks for the other ideas though!

Comment: There *is* in fact an API that is supposed to give this info: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=BWY.L&apikey=XXX

But it's blatantly wrong for most UK ones, giving GBP as the currency while most and/or all (who knows..) UK stocks seem to be in GBX/GBp..

Answer (score 0):

This one has a currency field:

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=IH2O.L&apikey=XXX

But abusing search for it does feel a little odd. Also the currency indicated in case of UK stocks is likely wrong since most UK stocks are listed in GBX (pence not pounds)...